# Read Excel File Data From OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm currently facing a problem whereby I don't know how to fix it.

I upload my precompiled project into IIS. Here is my purpose of this page:

- User upload a excel file into a folder in the server. ex `@"~/PlanQuantityFile/"`. It did upload successfully.

**Problems faced:**

- It stops when my scripts trying to open the excel file (for extract data purpose) without showing any errors. At line 881 as shown in the image.
- Here is few area I had seek for but it still couldn't solve my problem.

**Possible Solution:**

1. connection open but never close, so run out of connection. (but I did close it and the scripts stop running before the close statement)
2. 32 bit program calling 64 bit office. (I had limited knowledge on hardware field, don't know what should I do to troubleshoot here)
3. permission problem. Need to set the permission of ASP.NET account. (I still finding object names for ASP.NET account)

Thanks for anyone who trying to help. Your advice is invaluable.

```
OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + SaveLocation + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");

OleDbConnection connExcel = oledbConn;
OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

//Get the name of Sheet
try
{
    connExcel.Open();// It stops here without showing errors.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code returns a datatable for selected filelocation source. Remember to rename the sheetname to "Sheet1".

Use Namespace: using System.Data.OleDb;

Function::::

```
    public DataTable GetExcelinDatatable(string filelocation)
    {            
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filelocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [SHEET1$]", con);
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mentioned function to read the Excel file you have to just pass the path of excel file

```
 private List<DataTable> readExcel(string strXLS)
{
    //DataTable dtExcel = getExcelSheetTable();
    List<DataTable> SheetsData = new List<DataTable>();
    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    DataTable SocialMediaExcel = new DataTable();
    string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strXLS + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
    try
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connStr);
        adpt.Fill(dtExcel);
        SheetsData.Add(dtExcel);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }


    return SheetsData;
}
```